# "прОдал" и "продАл"? Возможны оба варианта?

Tags: орфоэпия

Раньше нормой был только вариант "прОдал". Сейчас, если я не ошибаюсь, возможны оба варианта.
 Есть ли какие-то правила, регламентирующие ударение в глаголах прошедшего времени? Помню, что в глаголах ж.р. ударение почти всегда падает на окончание. 
 И, если кто знает, подскажите: как в украинском языке с ударением в глаголах обстоит дело? Часто слышу "взЯла", "дАла" и тп (т.е. ударение остается на  основе). Интересно, это просто ошибка или как-то связано с украинским языком?
    Спасибо!

Comment: Украинский язык в Вашем примере совершенно ни при чем. Там своих заморочек с ударениями хватает. Дело тут просто в низкой речевой культуре говорящего. Зубрежка правил об ударениях в глаголах http://www.licey.net/russian/culture/1_2_4 даст немного. Просто нужно слушая - слышать правильную речь, тогда некультурная речь станет для Вас невозможной.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые правила ударения в глагольных формах все-таки есть. О них доступно рассказано в книге Н. Беляковой ["Как строится русский глагол?"](https://books.google.ee/books?id=bPVNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=wcarW9zyw7&sig=NSG1zyGYb4uQ7Wi80c8zKK_0vmM&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9z7-f8dbbAhXCa5oKHRJVBXo4ChDoAQhYMAk#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false) (2007).

1.3.2. Ударение в формах прошедшего времени
4) **ударение во всех формах**, кроме женского рода, **переходит на приставку**, в женском роде ударение падает на окончание (приставки, на которые может переходить ударение: *пере-, по-, под-, при-, от-, за-, из-, об-, до-, на-, про-, роз-, со-, у-*):

*приб**ы**ть — пр**и**был, пр**и**было, пр**и**были*, но *прибыл**а***;
*зад**а**ть — з**а**дал, з**а**дало, з**а**дали*, но *задал**а***.

У многих глаголов этой группы возможны колебания в выделении ударного слога, например: 
*прод**а**ть*
*пр**о**дал, пр**о**дало, пр**о**дали*, но *продал**а***;
*прод**а**л, прод**а**ло, прод**а**ли*, но *продал**а***.
**Обе формы соответствуют языковой норме.**

[Современный универсальный словарь русского языка](https://books.google.ee/books?id=fdEdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85&source=bl&ots=n3ltqLm0dc&sig=iuxzZctuxOOb1xxXiGCmo05ks2s&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ7uOT7dfbAhUHiKYKHe8xDnQQ6AEISzAH#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85&f=false) (Ю. Алабугина, О. Михайлова, Л. Субботина, М. Рут. 2013):
прод**а**ть, прод**а**м, прод**а**шь, пр**о**дал и прод**а**л, продал**а**.

[Русский орфографический словарь](https://lopatin.academic.ru/115150/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (РАН. ИРЯ им. В. В. Виноградова. В. В. Лопатин, Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.):
прод**а**ть, -**а**м, -**а**шь, -**а**ст, -ад**и**м, -ад**и**те, -ад**у**т; прош. вр. пр**о**д**а**л, -ал**а**, пр**о**д**а**ло.

Формы слов. Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку:
прода́ть, прода́л, про́дал, продала́, прода́ло, про́дало, прода́ли, про́дали.

Как видим, **большинство словарей высказывается за "равноправие" при выборе ударения.**

Особое мнение выражено в [словаре трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/6684/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (К. С. Горбачевич. 2000):
продать, *прош.* пр**о**дал (*допустимо* прод**а**л), продал**а** (*не рекомендуется* пр**о**дала, *неправильно* прод**а**ла), пр**о**дало, пр**о**дали (*допустимо* прод**а**ло, прод**а**ли); *прич.* прод**а**вший (*неправильно* пр**о**давший); *дееприч.* прод**а**в (*неправильно* пр**о**дав).

Comment: Римма, будьте осторожны с понятием равноправия: орфографические и другие не орфоэпические словари не указывают *уровни* нормы: хотя оба ударения (прОдал и продАл) литературны, первое считается образцовым (старшая норма), а второе относится к младшей норме (т. е. его словарная фиксация как нормативного варианта началась относительно недавно).

Comment: Ну, во-первых, я и так была предельно осторожна: поставила слово _равноправие_ в кавычки. Во-вторых, я тоже знаю правило о старших-младших позициях. Смотрите, в русском ОС — норма вообще не указана (сразу двояка), а у Зализняка — вообще на первом месте (прода́л).

Comment: из вашего ответа следует, что у вас есть «равноправие» (первые словари) — в чем тогда смысл этого «равноправия», если не в равнозначности? — а есть «особое мнение» (последний словарь), где как раз говорится не о «равноправии». Орфографические словари посвящены прежде всего _орфографии_, а материал по орфоэпическим нормам второстепенен и поверхностен.

Comment: Римма, прочитал ваш отредактированный комментарий: повторюсь -- ОС подробно рассматривает орфографию, а на "градацию" уровней орфоэпической нормы внимания не обращает. Словарь ААЗ вообще __грамматический__, он посвящен вопросам морфологии и словообразования, но никак не орфоэпии.

Answer (score 0):

Четких и универсальных правил русского ударения нет, поэтому стоит проверять произношение глаголов, вызывающих трудности, по словарю.

Ударение в слове *продал* **возможно и на первый, и на последний слог**: про́дал и *допуст.* продáл. Обратите внимание, что у второго варианта стоит помета *допуст.* – это значит, что в строгой литературной речи использовать его не следует.

Украинский язык тут ни при чем: все переносы типа *прóдал и продáл* демонстрируют законы живого русского словесного ударения.